# Extracting Date specific variable changes and plotting on timeline by ID

Tags: r, dataframe, timeline

I am trying to extract the dates at which a factor value changes (by unique IDs) so that I can plot across a timeline.

At this point, I am having a hard time extracting the data from the original data frame to even start producing the timeline.

An example data set would look something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1201, 10), rep(1202, 14)),
                date = c(seq(1,10,1), seq(2,15,1)),
                value = as.factor(c(rep(1, 5,), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 6), rep (1, 3), rep (2, 2), rep(3, 5))))
```

In which I have a sequence of dates which at some point, the factor variable (in this case "value) changes.  I need to extract the start and end date within each individual so that I can plot those across a timeline.

In this case, I would end up with a product that looks like:

```
out <- data.frame (id = c(rep(1201, 3), rep(1202, 4)), 
               date = c(1, 6, 9, 2, 6, 9, 11),
               value = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3))
```

From there, I would want to plot some form of timeline with each ID on the y-axis and date across the x-axis. What I envision is a horizontal bar graph where the color changes dependent on the value field. This way, you can visualize when each individual was on the same value across time.

Any help really is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split data by id. You may need a loop if you have many id's. The fact that you need a change in "value" per id made splitting the data necessary for my solution. Then write a function to compare the each "value" observation with the following. An `ifelse` statement can say: `if` the first observation for "value" == the second observation `then` delete that observation, `else` skip to next observation and repeat. Make sure to use data. table instead of data frame when recreating your reproducible example. I did this:

```
# install.packages(data.table) #  only if you do not have data table
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(id = c(rep(1201, 10), rep(1202, 14)),  # data.table not frame
                date = c(seq(1,10,1), seq(2,15,1)),
                value = as.factor(c(rep(1, 5,), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 6), rep (1, 3), rep (2, 2), rep(3, 5))))

z <- df[, unique(id)]

aa <- df[id==z[1]] ; bb <- df[id==z[2]]
```

This gives two groups based on id

```
aa

 # id date value
 # 1: 1201    1     1
 # 2: 1201    2     1
 # 3: 1201    3     1
 # 4: 1201    4     1
 # 5: 1201    5     1
 # 6: 1201    6     2
 # 7: 1201    7     2
 # 8: 1201    8     2
 # 9: 1201    9     3
# 10: 1201   10     3

bb

 #  id date value
 # 1: 1202    2     3
 # 2: 1202    3     3
 # 3: 1202    4     3
 # 4: 1202    5     3
 # 5: 1202    6     1
 # 6: 1202    7     1
 # 7: 1202    8     1
 # 8: 1202    9     2
 # 9: 1202   10     2
# 10: 1202   11     3
# 11: 1202   12     3
# 12: 1202   13     3
# 13: 1202   14     3
# 14: 1202   15     3
```

Now a function to remove rows where no change in "value" occurred:

```
value_change <- function(x,a) { 
  for(i in 1:length(x[,value])) {
    ifelse(x[a,value] == x[a+1,value], x <- x[-(a+1)], a <- a+1)}
  return(x)
  }
```

In this function argument `x` is the data.table (`aa` or `bb` in the example) and argument `a` is the row number to begin loop (should always be one).

```
value_change(aa, 1)

# id date value
# 1: 1201    1     1
# 2: 1201    6     2
# 3: 1201    9     3

value_change(bb, 1)

# id date value
# 1: 1202    2     3
# 2: 1202    6     1
# 3: 1202    9     2
# 4: 1202   11     3

aa <- value_change(aa, 1)
bb <- value_change(bb, 1)
dt_new <- rbind(aa,bb)
dt_new

#     id date value
# 1: 1201    1     1
# 2: 1201    6     2
# 3: 1201    9     3
# 4: 1202    2     3
# 5: 1202    6     1
# 6: 1202    9     2
# 7: 1202   11     3
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow extract the last Date from each "section" of data.   I have tried multiple attempts, and I can't seem to figure out how.  Basically, I want something that looks like:  out <- data.frame (id = c(rep(1201, 3), rep(1202, 4)),
                   startdate = c(1, 6, 9, 2, 6, 9, 11),
                   enddate = c(5, 8, 10, 5, 8, 10,15),
                   value = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3))

Comment: If you change the latter portion of the ifelse statement from `x <- x[-(a+1)], a <- a+1` to `x <- x[-(a)], a <- a+1)` you will get dates that correspond to the dates in the extra column you have requested. With this solution you would have to make two data.tables and collapse them in the end.

Comment: You can also change the second argument of the function from 1 to 2. This will give the second set of dates you want but because the function is primitive it will always include the first row for each id.